# Python rock paper scissors

Tags: python, python-2.x, rock-paper-scissors

My code implementing rock, paper and scissors in Python, using dicts to hold choices.

```
import random

choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

def choice():

    player_choice = raw_input('Choose rock, paper or scissors: ')
    if player_choice.lower() in choices:
        computer_choice = random.choice(choices)
        play(player_choice, computer_choice)
    else:
        choice()

def play(p_choice, c_choice):

    win_table = {'rock' : {'rock':'It was a Tie', 'paper':'You Lose', 'scissors':'You Win'},
                 'paper' : {'rock':'You Win', 'paper':'It was a Tie', 'scissors':'You Lose'},
                 'scissors' : {'rock':'You Lose', 'paper':'You Win', 'scissors':'It was a Tie'}}

    print 'Computer chose', c_choice
    print win_table[p_choice][c_choice]

    new = raw_input('Play again ? (Y/N):  ')
    if new.lower() == 'y': 
        choice()
    else:
        print 'Have a nice day !'

choice()
```

`win_table` dictionary names are player choices and dictionary keys are computer choices, seems more efficient to me. I haven't run any memory usage tests, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Single Responsibility Principle**

`choice()` should do one thing: get the player's choice. It does three things: gets the player's choice, picks a choice for the computer, and then plays.

If we just drop the other two, we'd get down to:

```
def choice():
    player_choice = raw_input('Choose rock, paper or scissors: ')
    if player_choice.lower() in choices:
        return player_choice
    else:
        return choice()
```

However, making this recursive isn't great. We could just run out of stack space. There's no advantage here. Let's just loop until done:

```
def choice():
    while True:
        player_choice = raw_input('Choose rock, paper or scissors: ')
        if player_choice.lower() in choices:
            return player_choice
```

It would be better to flip the namings here too, and call the function `player_choice` and the variable `choice`.

Similarly, `play()` does too many things. Ideally, you'd want to structure your main like:

```
while True:
    player = player_choice()    ## JUST grab the player's choice
    cpu = computer_choice()     ## JUST grab the CPU's choice
    show_results(player, cpu)   ## JUST print the outcome

    new = raw_input('Play again? (Y/N): ')
    if new.lower() != 'y':
        print 'Have a nice day!'
        break
```

**Determining Success**

Right now, your `win_table` is explicitly listing all 9 cases. That's super repetitive. First of all, the message is the same regardless of which win case we're in, so you could simplify the `win_table` to actually be a table of wins:

```
win_table = {'rock': ['scissors'],
             'scissors': ['paper'],
             'paper': ['rock']}

if cpu in win_table[player]:
    # You win!
```

Or we can do this programmaticly. Rock, Paper, Scissors is a wheel. Rock > Paper > Scissors > Rock. We win if the opponent's choice is the next one along in the wheel.

That is:

```
if player == cpu:
    # Tie
else:
    idx = choices.index(player)
    if cpu == choices[(idx + 1) % len(choices)]:
        # We win
    else:
        # We lose
```

Comment: Good points, thanks. I'll definitely be looking into it more carefully.

Comment: +1 for the mathematical insight. For more weapons: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors#Additional_weapons

Answer (score 5):

The biggest problem with this code is that you are using functions as glorified GOTO labels, when `choice()` is called from within `choice`, when `choice()` is called from `play`, and when `choice()` is called initially.  If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> after a few rounds, you'll see that the call stack is inappropriately deep.  The remedy is to use functions, return values, and loops properly.

The other change I would suggest is removing the redundancy between the `choices` list and the `win_table`.

```
import random

MOVES = {
    'rock': {'rock':'It was a Tie', 'paper':'You Lose', 'scissors':'You Win'},
    'paper': {'rock':'You Win', 'paper':'It was a Tie', 'scissors':'You Lose'},
    'scissors': {'rock':'You Lose', 'paper':'You Win', 'scissors':'It was a Tie'},
}

def choices():
    """Produce a tuple of the player's choice and the computer's choice."""
    while True:
        player_choice = raw_input('Choose rock, paper or scissors: ')
        if player_choice.lower() in MOVES:
            computer_choice = random.choice(MOVES.keys())
            return player_choice, computer_choice

def reveal(p_choice, c_choice):
    """Print both players' choices and the result of the game."""
    print 'Computer chose', c_choice
    print MOVES[p_choice][c_choice]

def play():
    """Play a round of rock-paper-scissors, then repeat if desired."""
    while True:
        reveal(*choices())
        if raw_input('Play again? (Y/N):  ').lower() != 'y':
            break
    print 'Have a nice day!'

play()
```

There isn't much benefit to having `choices()` produce both the player's choice and the computer's choice, though.  You should break that up into two functions.